# getting context.read() functionality inside build

Tags: flutter, dart, state, provider, state-management

Calling context.read() inside build is not safe. Thus it raises an error but Provider.of(context, listen = false) is allowed for backwards compatibility but it still is unsafe. How can one get the context.read() functionality inside build.

**One solution I found:**

In you model add two values, one that will change and the other will not:

```
class MyModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  double value = 45;
  double thisValueWillNeverChange = 45;
}
```

In your Widget call `value` where the value needs to changed and should cause the widget to rebuild but use the `thisValueWillNeverChange` where you just want to read the initial value and dont want to update the widget.

You can access both values with context.select() or context.watch().

**Kind of app where I want to implement this functionality:**
[image]

As you can see that the title in the appBar is going to have the `thisValueWillNeverChange` so it stays static but the text and the slider will change and will use `value`.

**At the start the app will start with everything having the initial value as 45.0**